# Collation for German characters

Tags: mysql, unicode, character, translation, collation

Basically, I've read a few threads when I had trouble getting German special characters like ü,ö,ä,ß to show up when a user uses them in a submission title.

To say the least, they look like this: `Ã¼Ã¶Ã¤Ã�`

Turns out the database collation was wrong for these types of characters (or so I've read) the collation was latin1_swedish_ci, and I've read to change it to u8_general_ci or utf8_unicode_ci. Well I've tried both but on submission to the database by a user, the title with special characters still shows up the same, all messed up like above.

I guess my question is, what am I doing wrong? Is there an extra step I've missed to get these characters to show correctly? I've never worked with German translation before this particular project, and this is my first time with this. So any help would be fantastic.

Comment: Are you serving your pages as UTF-8, via either the `Content-Type` HTTP header or a `meta` in the HTML itself?

Comment: I have <META HTTP-EQUIV="content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8"> at the top of the page in which I'm trying to have the characters show correctly. So yeah.